# Error build shows NextJS instead of NuxtJS

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I've create a project using
`yarn create nuxt-app <project-name>`

Then chose to add tailwind to the app. When i run the app i get this though...

`localhost:3000`

[image]

I've i run the app on my laptop it works, but if i run it on the desktop it does not work. The gitignore are the same. I'm not sure what is wrong? I've placed a copy of my project here if someone could help me please.

I'd expect to see the nuxtjs logo...

[image]

It's just the default boiler plate stuff for a vue, nuxt with tailwind project.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ljf8a0ixel9ij0n/kanri-frontend-main.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am very sure you just started the wrong project. Did you run the start command from the wrong folder maybe? The files you provided are the nuxt ones, there is nothing with next in them. Please double check you did the "npm run dev" or the yarn command or whatever you're using from the correct project folder.

Comment: I will try that thank you for at least double-checking I appreciate it

Comment: I'm using yarn, and running yarn dev from the root folder location but still get the same webpage as shown above, not the correct one.

Comment: does it work for you when you run it by chance?

Comment: I found out for whatever i reason i have to run the project on a different port. for whatever reason it Nextjs is 3000. i have no idea why or how. i don't have anything else running